# Does Spring Boot framework have a middleware pipeline to handle HTTP requests like asp.net core?

Tags: spring-boot

I want to handle the request via several components like asp.net core not just mapping the request to a service, especially when an exception happens I want to redirect the request to the error page.

I want to create a middleware pipeline to handle http requests in Spring Boot.

Comment: Not familiar with middleware pipeline in asp.net but, from what you describe, you are looking for `Filter`

Comment: The equivalent to ASP.NET core middleware are the `HandlerInterceptor` which are getting invoked *before* our controllers. `Filter` are part of the webserver itself e.g. for security purpose. ASP.NET core middleware sits between servlet and controllers / endpoints. Authorisation and so on happens before reaching the middleware. Therefore I suggest to have a look at the `HandlerInterceptor` in spring.